# How to exclude settings.json from VS Code search

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I thought maybe I would achieve it with this:

```
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\settings.json": true
  }
```

But without luck.

Answer (score 2):

```json
"search.exclude": {
    // ...
    "**/settings.json": true
}
```

And reload editor. It will remove from search `settings.json` in all folders.

> Note: if `settings.json` is opened it will still emerge in the search
>   result.

Comment: "files.exclude" instead of "search.exclued" works at my VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the filename settings.json in the left panel you can copy the path by right-clicking.  I get something like:

```
C:\Users\Mark\experimental\.vscode\settings.json
```

with "experimental" as the workspace root.  Then it is a question of how/whether to escape those backslashes but a little experimentation should get you there.

Comment: I exclude entire .vscode folder in workspace root with:   "**/.vscode": true. This is different, the path i see in the left panel is the path i included in the post above, it goes to AppData folder